# Class that is a custom visual wrapper, with Avalonia

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui, avalonia

I want to repeat a design pattern from Maui in Avalonia. I want to define a class `Card` that takes any visual content and puts it in a customizable wrapper. Here's an illustration of what I'm looking for:

```
<ContentView xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Class="MyNameSpace.Card">
    <Border BackgroundColor="#888888">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Text="This is a card, and here is the content:" />

            <ContentPresenter /> 

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</ContentView >
```

And this is how I want to use it on the `ContentPage`:

```
<components:Card>
    <TextBlock>Here is a button</TextBlock>
    <Button>Click here</Button>
</components:Card>

<components:Card>
    <TextBlock>Here are two more buttons</TextBlock>
    <Button>Click here</Button>
    <Button>Click here</Button>
</components:Card>

<components:Card>
    <Image Source="[path]">
</components:Card>
```

Can something like this be done in Avalonia?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to approach this, you could make a custom TemplatedControl that derives from ContentControl, but that might be overkill.  However if you absolutely want to use the control as a named "Card" object that is the way to do it.  A simpler way to use a content control and apply a style that modifies the ControlTemplate.  With this method you won't have a "Card" object.

The following example assumes you are putting this in a UserControl (not required).  You can, of course, customize the style selector to suit your needs (if you have content controls that you do NOT want to use this style, for example).

If you do want the Card object, you just have to make a new TemplatedControl, make it derive from ContentControl, and add the style below to it's XAMl.

```xml
<UserControl.Styles>
    <Style Selector="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border Background="#888888">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="This is a card, and here is the content:" />
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Styles>

<Grid RowDefinitions="*,*">
    <ContentControl>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>Here is a button</TextBlock>
            <Button>Click here</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentControl>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>Here are two more buttons</TextBlock>
            <Button>Click here</Button>
            <Button>Click here</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```